# Deserialize an xml not extract the object

Tags: c#, xml

I want to deserialize an XML string to an object. the execution don't return an error or an exception. I search in net but don't find any solution that I can apply to my issue.

```
XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
xRoot.ElementName = "Get_mouvements_usersResult";
xRoot.Namespace = "urn:DME_Webservices";
xRoot.IsNullable = false;

trueObject="<ns1:Get_mouvements_usersResult xmlns:ns1=\"urn:DME_Webservices\"><Obj_info_retour><flag_erreur>false</flag_erreur><libelle_erreur/><libelle_detail_erreur/></Obj_info_retour><tab_Cuser_mouvements><obj_cuser><IPP>02084</IPP><Id_user>4503843842</Id_user><civilite>Mme</civilite><nom_usuel>BOTTU</nom_usuel><nom_naissance>LOACU</nom_naissance><prenom>Alida</prenom><date_naissance>19340707</date_naissance><numro_sejour>31202084001</numro_sejour><date_deb_sejour>20150420113700</date_deb_sejour><code_lit>504</code_lit><code_etablissement>000312</code_etablissement></obj_cuser><tab_obj_Cmouvement>Id_mouvement>4505631384</Id_mouvement><date_mouvement>20150420113700</date_mouvement><code_mouvement>E</code_mouvement><Libelle_mouvement>Entre tablissement</Libelle_mouvement><code_ufh>ETG1</code_ufh><libelle_ufh>Etage 1-Chteau de Fermaincourt</libelle_ufh><code_ufm>SSR_HC_CONVA</code_ufm><libelle_ufm>Convalescence</libelle_ufm><Date_fin_mouvement>20150422152600</Date_fin_mouvement><code_lit>402</code_lit><comm_mouvement/>/tab_obj_Cmouvement><tab_obj_Cmouvement><Id_mouvement>4533166359</Id_mouvement><date_mouvement>20150422152600</date_mouvement><code_mouvement>M</code_mouvement><Libelle_mouvement>Mutation</Libelle_mouvement>code_ufh>ETG3</code_ufh><libelle_ufh>Etage 3 - La Chapelle Royale</libelle_ufh><code_ufm>SSR_HC_CONVA</code_ufm><libelle_ufm>Convalescence</libelle_ufm><Date_fin_mouvement>20150730142100</Date_fin_mouvement>code_lit>605D</code_lit><comm_mouvement/></tab_obj_Cmouvement><tab_obj_Cmouvement><Id_mouvement>5125097053</Id_mouvement><date_mouvement>20150730142100</date_mouvement><code_mouvement>M</code_mouvement><Libelle_mouvement>Mutation</Libelle_mouvement><code_ufh>ETG2</code_ufh><libelle_ufh>Etage 2 - Domaine de Comteville</libelle_ufh><code_ufm>SSR_HC_SDSG</code_ufm><libelle_ufm>Griatrie</libelle_ufm><Date_fin_mouvement/><code_lit>504</code_lit><comm_mouvement/></tab_obj_Cmouvement></tab_Cuser_mouvements></ns1:Get_mouvements_usersResult>";

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(trueObject));

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlUsers), xRoot);

listXmlUserMove = (XmlUsers)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
```

I have these classes:

```
    [Serializable, XmlRoot("ns1:Get_mouvements_usersResult"), XmlType("ns1:Get_mouvements_usersResult")]
    public class XmlUsers
    {
        [XmlElement("tab_Cuser_mouvements")]
        public List<XmlUserMove> UserList { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Obj_info_retour")]
        public SoapResult soapResult { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType("Obj_info_retour")]
    public class SoapResult
    {
        [XmlElement("flag_erreur")]
        public string ErrorFlag { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("libelle_erreur")]
        public string ErrorName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("libelle_detail_erreur")]
        public string ErrorDetails { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType("tab_Cuser_mouvements")]
    public class XmlUserMove
    {
        [XmlElement("obj_cuser")]
        public XmlUser user { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("tab_obj_Cmouvement")]
        public List<XmlMove> MoveList { get; set; }
    }

    public class XmlUser
    {
        [XmlElementAttribute("IPP")]
        public string IPP { get; set; }

        [XmlElementAttribute("Id_patient")]
        public string IdUser { get; set; }

        [XmlElementAttribute("civilite")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [XmlElementAttribute("nom_usuel")]
        public string UsedLastName { get; set; }

        [XmlElementAttribute("nom_naissance")]
        public string BirthLastName { get; set; }

        [XmlElementAttribute("prenom")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [XmlElementAttribute("date_naissance")]
        public string Birthday { get; set; }

        [XmlElementAttribute("numero_sejour")]
        public string RoomNumber { get; set; }

        [XmlElementAttribute("date_deb_sejour")]
        public string EntredDate { get; set; }

        [XmlElementAttribute("code_lit")]
        public string BedCode { get; set; }

        [XmlElementAttribute("code_etablissement")]
        public string DivisionCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class XmlMove
    {
        [XmlElement("Id_mouvement")]
        public string MoveId { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("date_mouvement")]
        public string MoveDate { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("code_mouvement")]
        public string MoveCode { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Libelle_mouvement")]
        public string MoveName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("code_ufh")]
        public string ufhCode { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("libelle_ufh")]
        public string UfhName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("code_ufm")]
        public string UfmCode { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("libelle_ufm")]
        public string UfmName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Date_fin_mouvement")]
        public string MoveEndDate { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("code_lit")]
        public string BedCode { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("comm_mouvement")]
        public string MoveComm { get; set; }
    }
```

The `listXmlUserMove` object don't contain anything but the xml contain many things.

Any one can help me please?

Comment: Try https://blog.udemy.com/csharp-serialize-to-xml/

Comment: Looks like you are missing the XmlUser class definition in the code provided.

Comment: Also there are a bunch of characters missing from your `trueObject` XML string. They may or may not be causing you issues, depending on whether or not it was just a copy/paste error here on stack overflow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have copied the wrong string in my question. sorry. The correct string is not containing error. I tested it in this site http://xmlbeautifier.com/. I Forgot to copy the XmlUser class. I will add it

Answer (score 1):

There are a few `<` characters missing from your `trueObject`, and you didn't include the `XmlUser` class, but since you reported an empty object and not an exception, I'm assuming what you have is really ok, and that was just a copy/paste error.

---

You don't need to declare the `xRoot` object separately if you get the attributes on `XmlUsers` set up correctly. `ns1` is meaningless without context. You should use the `Namespace` property to give the info to those attributes correctly.

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("Get_mouvements_usersResult", Namespace = "urn:DME_Webservices"), XmlType("Get_mouvements_usersResult", Namespace = "urn:DME_Webservices")]
public class XmlUsers
```

---

Your elements aren't coming through because of a namespace issue. `XmlUsers`'s Namespace is assumed to apply to the elements inside of it. In your actual XML, though, they are in a different namespace. Since they have no xmlns defined, they're in the default namespace, an empty string. The element's namespaces should be set explicitly:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("Get_mouvements_usersResult", Namespace = "urn:DME_Webservices"), XmlType("Get_mouvements_usersResult", Namespace = "urn:DME_Webservices")]
public class XmlUsers
{
    [XmlElement("tab_Cuser_mouvements", Namespace = "")]
    public List<XmlUserMove> UserList { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Obj_info_retour", Namespace = "")]
    public SoapResult soapResult { get; set; }
}
```

If you had intended everything to be inside `ns1`, then you'll need to rework your XML files and classes to match that.

So now the code to deserialize looks like this (note, this includes my fixed `trueObject` string)

```
var trueObject="<ns1:Get_mouvements_usersResult xmlns:ns1=\"urn:DME_Webservices\"><Obj_info_retour><flag_erreur>false</flag_erreur><libelle_erreur/><libelle_detail_erreur/></Obj_info_retour><tab_Cuser_mouvements><obj_cuser><IPP>02084</IPP><Id_user>4503843842</Id_user><civilite>Mme</civilite><nom_usuel>BOTTU</nom_usuel><nom_naissance>LOACU</nom_naissance><prenom>Alida</prenom><date_naissance>19340707</date_naissance><numro_sejour>31202084001</numro_sejour><date_deb_sejour>20150420113700</date_deb_sejour><code_lit>504</code_lit><code_etablissement>000312</code_etablissement></obj_cuser><tab_obj_Cmouvement><Id_mouvement>4505631384</Id_mouvement><date_mouvement>20150420113700</date_mouvement><code_mouvement>E</code_mouvement><Libelle_mouvement>Entre tablissement</Libelle_mouvement><code_ufh>ETG1</code_ufh><libelle_ufh>Etage 1-Chteau de Fermaincourt</libelle_ufh><code_ufm>SSR_HC_CONVA</code_ufm><libelle_ufm>Convalescence</libelle_ufm><Date_fin_mouvement>20150422152600</Date_fin_mouvement><code_lit>402</code_lit><comm_mouvement/></tab_obj_Cmouvement><tab_obj_Cmouvement><Id_mouvement>4533166359</Id_mouvement><date_mouvement>20150422152600</date_mouvement><code_mouvement>M</code_mouvement><Libelle_mouvement>Mutation</Libelle_mouvement><code_ufh>ETG3</code_ufh><libelle_ufh>Etage 3 - La Chapelle Royale</libelle_ufh><code_ufm>SSR_HC_CONVA</code_ufm><libelle_ufm>Convalescence</libelle_ufm><Date_fin_mouvement>20150730142100</Date_fin_mouvement><code_lit>605D</code_lit><comm_mouvement/></tab_obj_Cmouvement><tab_obj_Cmouvement><Id_mouvement>5125097053</Id_mouvement><date_mouvement>20150730142100</date_mouvement><code_mouvement>M</code_mouvement><Libelle_mouvement>Mutation</Libelle_mouvement><code_ufh>ETG2</code_ufh><libelle_ufh>Etage 2 - Domaine de Comteville</libelle_ufh><code_ufm>SSR_HC_SDSG</code_ufm><libelle_ufm>Griatrie</libelle_ufm><Date_fin_mouvement/><code_lit>504</code_lit><comm_mouvement/></tab_obj_Cmouvement></tab_Cuser_mouvements></ns1:Get_mouvements_usersResult>";

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(trueObject));

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlUsers));

var listXmlUserMove = (XmlUsers)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
```

But the object is actually populated at the end!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have copied the wrong string in my question. sorry. The correct string is not containing error. I tested it in this site xmlbeautifier.com. I Forgot to copy the XmlUser class. I will add it.

Comment: I had modified with your suggestion but now I have an exception error : "<Get_mouvements_patientsResult xmlns='urn:DME_Webservices'> was not expected.". But when I add the xRoot it works :). Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I do what Tim S. tell me but I don't remove the xRoot :

```
XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
xRoot.ElementName = "Get_mouvements_usersResult";
xRoot.Namespace = "urn:DME_Webservices";
xRoot.IsNullable = false;
```

.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlUsers), xRoot);
```

Now the solution work fine.
Thank you for your help :)